# Can you take the 2's complement of an already negative number?

Tags: binary

So for example, if we were to try and take the 2's complement of -8. Would this be un-representable or would doing the 2's complement result in a positive 8?

Answer (score 1):

$-8$ when converted to binary gives $11111000$

Flipping the digits give $00000111$

Add $1$ we get  $00001000$ which is equal to $8$

Comment: Ah that makes much more sense. Thank you.